# woocommerce store url without login as admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new on wordpress. I added woocommerce for creating store page.

When I login as admin I see store page on `http://IP/wordpress/?post_type=product`. I am going that with "visit store" in admin page.

But I didnt see store page without login. I search about it and I found that default store url is `http://IP/wordpress/shop`. But it didnt work.

How can I see store page when I am not login?

Comment: It sounds like you need to adjust your permalink settings. Are you running on a Linux or Windows host? This can also be problematic specifically with regards to permalink structures on some older versions of IIS (Windows)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16,04. I checked permalinks on `dashboard/settings/permalinks`. There are url for product pages. What should I do?